# Stacking Nav LI Items Dynamically based on page width

Tags: html, css

My li items are taking up the full width of their text and creating a second line in the  instead of breaking downward into the li itself. I've tried the following but it's not really providing that responsive sizing I'm looking to add.

```
.sub-nav li > a {
    width: min-content;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

https://www.harpercollege.edu/academics/index.php

Answer (score 0):

change CSS rule `.sub-nav ul` to this:

```css
.sub-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: min-content;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

You may want to reduce font size, and use condensed font https://fonts.google.com/?query=condensed

Comment: That won't allow it to shrink down dynamically and I'll have to add a break point at which it transitions to that style.

Comment: ohh i see. I've modified the answer. change `.sub-nav ul` rule. And if you zoom in zoom out you'll see the change.